# regex doesn't match last word

Tags: regex, delphi

I have this simple regex:

```
RegEx_Seek_1 := TDIPerlRegEx.Create{$IFNDEF DI_No_RegEx_Component}(nil){$ENDIF};
s1 := '(doesn''t|don''t|can''t|cannot|shouldn''t|wouldn''t|couldn''t|havn''t|hadn't)';
// s1 contents this text: (doesn't|don't|can't|cannot|shouldn't|wouldn't|couldn't|havn't|hadn't)
RegEx_Seek_1.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m)'+s1+' (a |the )(ear|law also|multitude|son)(?(?= of)( \* | \w+ )| )([^»Ô¶ ][^ »Ô¶]\w*)';
```

Which is targeted on finding noun with an article, which can be followed by `of`. If there is `of`, then I need to search for noun `\w+` (and `\*` too; substitude for verb). The last word should be verb.

The sample text:

```
. some text . Doesn't the ear try ...
. some text doesn't the law also say ...
. some text doesn't the son bear ...
. some text . Shouldn't the multitude of words be answered? ...
. some text . Why doesn't the son of * come to eat ...
```

My results:

```
Doesn't the ear try
doesn't the law also say
doesn't the son bear
Shouldn't the multitude of words
```

And it fails to get the last sentence: 
`doesn't the son of * come`

My plan is to add \K before the last word to get the verb.

The exclusion of the characters:
`[^»Ô¶]` is made because `»`, `Ô`, `¶` already represent some mark in the text, to decribe a existing verb. They may or may be not present. I am using spaces. Tabs are delimitors and are not part of any sentence.

In this regex I included a space `[^»Ô¶ ]` to get the last word.

So the question is how to correct the regex to get one more line:
`doesn't the son of * come`

Edit:

I need to refer the verbs in the same group while replacing (I will refer to verb).

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/haZJDW/4

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: sorry I missed to add `be answered?` after the word `words`. This means that if you add take the sentence  `Shouldn't the multitude of words be answered?` the words is captured instead of be. This is why I had the if condtion there. I need to refer the verbs in the same group while replacing.

Comment: That becomes too broach at this moment. You should always consider cases like `Shouldn't the multitude of words have been answered?`, `Shouldn't the multitude of words in this letter of my friend be answered?`, etc. Not sure you can do that with regex without listing all possible word forms you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in `(?(?= of)( \* | \w+ )| )`.

Remember that lookaheads don't move the cursor forward, so the `( \* | \w+ )` will match `of` , so the remainder is now `* come` which can't be matched by `([^»Ô¶ ][^ »Ô¶]\w*)` as the second character is a space.

I guess you should match the of already in your condition, like `(?(?= of) of( \* | \w+ )| )`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the Wiktor's pattern to match:

```
(*UCP)(?m)'+s1+' (a |the )(ear|law also|multitude|son)(?:\s+of Words|\s+of \*)*\s+\K(?P<verb>[^\s»Ô¶]+)
```

Now I can refer to the last group like this:

```
char(182)+'$<verb>'
```

I show my results how the verb was changed using `Replace2` function of TDIRegEx. You see it works:

Why doesn't the son of * **¶come** to eat

Doesn't the ear **¶try** words,

Why doesn't the son **¶bear** the

doesn't the law also **¶say** the same thing?

Shouldn't the multitude of words **¶be** answered?

Both answers, the one from Wictor and the one from Sebastian helped me to solve the question. Thank you.